# How i can stop reading values after EOF

Tags: c, stdin, eof, getchar

I have little problem with my code. I try to make 'while' loop which will read all my input values and then stop when i clicked EOF. I have read that EOF in windows is CTRL+Z and so on but my 'while' doesn't want to stop and after all input values and CTRL+Z, it stay and wait for next values.
This is my code and hope you will help me thanks):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h> 

#define gc getchar



inline int scan_integer();
inline void zaprzeczenie(bool*);


int main() {
  bool rosnie=true;

  int poprzednia;
  register int terazniejsza;


  terazniejsza = scan_integer();
  poprzednia = terazniejsza;

  int sumaAktualnego=terazniejsza;
  int sumaNajwiekszego=terazniejsza;

  int iloscAktualnego=1;
  int iloscNajwiekszego=0;

  int staly=1;
  int sumaStalego=0;


  while(!feof(stdin))
  {
    printf("%d ",terazniejsza);
    terazniejsza = scan_integer();


    if(terazniejsza<poprzednia){
        if(rosnie){
            if(iloscAktualnego>iloscNajwiekszego){
                iloscNajwiekszego=iloscAktualnego;
                sumaNajwiekszego=sumaAktualnego;
            }
            iloscAktualnego=1;
            sumaAktualnego=terazniejsza;

            if(staly>1){
                iloscAktualnego+=staly;
                sumaAktualnego+=sumaStalego;
                staly=1;
                sumaStalego=0;
            }

            zaprzeczenie(&rosnie);
        }
        else{
            sumaAktualnego+=terazniejsza;
            iloscAktualnego++;
        }
    }
    else if(terazniejsza>poprzednia){
        if(rosnie){
            sumaAktualnego+=terazniejsza;
            iloscAktualnego++;
        }
        else{
            if(iloscAktualnego>iloscNajwiekszego){
                iloscNajwiekszego=iloscAktualnego;
                sumaNajwiekszego=sumaAktualnego;
            }
            iloscAktualnego=1;
            sumaAktualnego=terazniejsza;

            if(staly>0){
                iloscAktualnego+=staly;
                sumaAktualnego+=sumaStalego;
                staly=1;
                sumaStalego=0;
            }

            zaprzeczenie(&rosnie);
        }
    }
    else if(terazniejsza==poprzednia){
        staly++;
        sumaStalego+=poprzednia;
        sumaStalego+=terazniejsza;
        sumaAktualnego+=terazniejsza;
        iloscAktualnego++;
    }

    poprzednia=terazniejsza;
}
  if(iloscAktualnego>iloscNajwiekszego){
      iloscNajwiekszego=iloscAktualnego;
      sumaNajwiekszego=sumaAktualnego;
  }

  printf("%d %d",iloscNajwiekszego, sumaNajwiekszego);
 }

 inline int scan_integer()
{
  register int c = gc();
  int wejsciowa = 0;
  for( ; ((c<48 || c>57)); c = gc() );

  for( ;c>47 && c<58; c = gc() ) {
      wejsciowa = (wejsciowa << 1) + (wejsciowa << 3) + c - 48;
  }
  return wejsciowa;
}

inline void zaprzeczenie(bool* boo){
  boo=!boo;
}
```

P.S.:Sorry for polish variables)

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/1679849)

Comment: Need to test when `gc()` returns `EOF`.

Comment: i've tried to test gc() when it returns EOF but gc() didn't return EOF at all.

Comment: this line: `boo=!boo;` results in the compiler raising a warning: 115:6: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast,  This line is trying to compliment a pointer.  Suggest; `*boo =!*boo;`

Comment: `true` is any value except 0.  better to use `bool rosnie=~false;`

Comment: this function: `inline void zaprzeczenie(bool* boo){
  boo=!boo;
}` just clutters the code.   Better to replace all calls to that function with: `rosnie = ~rosnie;` Suggest look up the difference between a 1's compliment and a 2's compliment

Comment: in modern C, the modifier `register` has no effect other than the address of the variable cannot be acquired.  Strongly suggest not using the `register` modifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define gc getchar
```

Please don't do this - it makes it harder for others to read and understand your code.

`while( !feof( stream ))` doesn't work the way most people expect it to, and will wind up looping one too many times.  Instead, you need to check the result of your last input operation.  Since you're using `getchar`, you can check the result of that:

```
while ( (terazniejsza = scan_integer()) != EOF )
{
  ...
}

...

inline int scan_integer()
{
  register int c = gc();
  int wejsciowa = 0;
  for( ; ((c<48 || c>57) && c != EOF ); c = gc() );

  for( ;c>47 && c<58 && c != EOF; c = gc() ) {
      wejsciowa = (wejsciowa << 1) + (wejsciowa << 3) + c - 48;
  }
  return c != EOF ? wejsciowa : c;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't work... 'While' doesn't want to stop waiting and seems like scan_ineger doesn't want to return EOF or it return not EOF...